# If $(X,F)$ is a measurable space and $∼$ is an equivalence relation, is there a $σ$-algebra on $X/∼$ which can be canonically embedded into $F$?

Tags: measure-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Let

- $(X,\mathcal X)$ be a measurable space
- $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$
- $X/\sim$ denote the quotient space of $X$ by $\sim$

> Is there a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal X/\sim$ on $X/\sim$ such that $\mathcal X$ is "canonically" embedded into $\mathcal X$?

If necessary, assume that $(Y,\mathcal Y)$ is another measurable space such that $\sim$ is the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(set_theory)#As_a_subset_of_the_square) of a $(\mathcal X,\mathcal Y)$-measurable function $f:X\to Y$. Maybe we can define an equivalence relation (denoted by the same symbol $\sim$) on $\mathcal F$ via $$A\sim A':\Leftrightarrow\exists B\in\mathcal G:A,A'\subseteq f^{-1}(B)\tag1\;\;\;\text{for }A,A'\in\mathcal F$$ in that case. However, I'm mostly interested in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Any function $f:X\to Y$ induces a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal Y$ on $Y$ characterized by:$$B\in \mathcal Y\iff f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal X$$

If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$ then we have the natural function $\nu:X\to X/\sim$ that is prescribed by:$$x\mapsto\text{ equivalence class represented by }x$$

Applying the procedure on function $\nu$ we find the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal Y$ that is characterized by:$$B\in\mathcal Y\iff\cup B\in\mathcal X$$So that $\mathcal Y=\{\cup B\mid B\in\mathcal X\}$.

This is the first (and for me only) $\sigma$-algebra that comes to mind in this situation. However, I am not sure whether this is really what you are after.

Comment: You should add that the surjectivity of $ν$ implies the injectivity of $ν^{-1}$, so that $ν^{-1} \colon \mathcal Y → \mathcal X$ is indeed an embedding. Ah, no. Sorry, this is already implied by your last line. No, wait …

Comment: Are you sure about your last line? Isn’t it more like $\mathcal Y \cong \{\bigcup B;~B ∈ \mathcal Y\} ⊆ \mathcal X$? (That is, $\mathcal Y \cong \operatorname{img} ν^{-1} = …$?)